# What's the use of the offset in mmap?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, offset, mmap

I come across this from time to time in my operating systems class but the professor didn't explain it and I can't exactly find an explanation online. What exactly is the use of the offset in `mmap` ? Also this is for linux

Thanks

Comment: The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) seems pretty clear. What specifically don't you understand about this: "The contents of a file mapping (as opposed to an anonymous mapping;
       see MAP_ANONYMOUS below), are initialized using length bytes **starting
       at offset offset in the file**"

Comment: so basically, lets say that process 1 has a data segment starting from 0x10000 going to 0x11000, and I put offset as 0x10500, half of the data will get will get shared? The course is in French so sometimes its a bit confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It lets you map a section of a file that doesn't necessarily start at the beginning.

So

```
fd = open("/path/to/myfile", O_RDONLY);
ptr = mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 4096);
```

would map bytes 4096-12287 of the file into memory, and return a pointer to the address where they are mapped.

This is useful, for instance, if you are loading a shared library.  Some parts of the file may be headers or debug info that you don't need to map into memory.